# Visual Studio 2005: can not build solution

Tags: visual-studio-2005

I am unable to build solution because I get the following error

The command "c:\mypath\myapp.dll" move "c:\mypath1\" exited with code1.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a post-build command to move a dll from one location to another.  I believe the syntax for the command should be "move [source path] [destination path]"

Answer (score 0):

Verify the POST Build events from the Project Properties, Build events.